# How to create a JavaScript date object from a JSON store?

Tags: javascript, json, datetime, extjs, doctrine

I have following JSON response created by Doctrine 2 as a datetime entity in server-side and encoded as JSON by zend framework`s Zend_Json::encode($stores) method:

```
{
"birthdate":
{"date":"2011-08-19 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"}
}
```

I need to create a new Date() using  this JSON for my Extjs data grid but I can't figure out how to manipulate JSON response. Assuming I have a JSON store and I can access to birthdate object, new Date(birthdate.date) gives "Date {Invalid Date}".new Date("date":"2011-08-19 00:00:00") gives the same error but new Date("date":"2011-08-19") works fine.
Please advice me on how to create a date object from my JSON store.

Comment: The best thing would be to re-design the way the date is stored in the first place, to make construction of the Date object easier. Specifically, it would be much more useful if the date were stored such that the component numeric values (year, month, etc) were all available as **numbers** instead of embedded in a string.

Comment: I removed my initial answer, and I think you do have to rethink it in general, but **none of the answers below takes your timezone into consideration**. Is that what you were trying to pass with the `timezone_type` and `timezone` parameters? Except for **Nyozeko** who just points you to the parse method.

Comment: @ZenMaster you are right.non of the answers cover how to use timezone returned by server.returned stuff is managed by doctrine 2and i have no clue on how to use it in my js code yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the date using the following code

```
Date.parseDate("2011-08-19 00:00:00", "Y-m-d h:i:s");
```

[API Doc](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/docs/)

As per ExtJS 4.0 the method is changed as `parse`

```
Ext.Date.parse("2011-08-19 00:00:00", "Y-m-d h:i:s")
```

[API Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date)

Comment: `parseDate` is a ExtJS 2.x extension to the Date Object.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and helping me.your solution is working perfectly but the timezone which is returned by server is not implemented and i will have to work on that.

Answer (score 1):

That string isn't something that the `Date` constructor or `Date.parse` can understand.  It can, however, understand the "YY-MM-DD" portion, though, so if that's enough granularity, you can do this:

```
var data = {
    "birthdate": {
        "date": "2011-08-19 00:00:00",
        "timezone_type": 3,
        "timezone":"Europe\/Berlin"
    }
};
// just parse the 'YY-MM-DD' part
new Date(data.birthdate.date.split(' ')[0]);
```

---

Edit: when I say that format can't be parsed, I mean in a cross-browser way.  The latest Chrome, for example, understands the string just fine, whereas the latest FF does not.  The 'YY-MM-DD' portion should be plenty cross-browser though (be sure to test and verify that though, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try Date.parse ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

If it is not parsed, you'll have to reformat the string format.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse your string to get a Date object ([see here](http://jsfiddle.net/hxMy5/)):

```
var yourDate = Date.parse("2011-08-19 00:00:00");
```